# Source code customization for specific words?

Tags: listings, verbatim, fancyvrb

I'd like to highlight some specific words for HTML5 code manually in LaTeX. In other words, I don't want to define an exact structure for highlighting the language, but do the highlights only for the words I select. So let's say for the code below, I only want to make `signin-login` bold and green, and only its `type="text"` bold and red, while the rest of the code stays the same.

```
    <form id="navbar-loginform" class="navbar-form navbar-right hidden">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input id="signin-login" highlight="" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input id= "signin-password" highlight="" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" type="password">
    </div>
    <button highlight="" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
    </form>
```

How can I achieve this? Could you please show me a short working example for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide some more information on how you are working. Add a minimal working example showing your documentclass, the packages you want to use herefore and the `\begin{document}...\end{document}`-Block.

Comment: Maybe this link helps you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91259/changing-color-of-text-snippet-in-a-verbatim-environment

Comment: otherwise the `listings`-package might do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility using the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package; since apparently you only want to highlight some specific strings, you can escape to LaTeX and do the coloring there (in my example I used the `bera` package just to have a mono-spaced font allowing boldface)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{bera}% for boldfaced typewriter font

\lstset{
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
columns=fullflexible,
breaklines=true,
escapeinside={@|}{|@}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
    <form id="navbar-loginform" class="navbar-form navbar-right hidden">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input id="@|\color{red}\bfseries signin-login|@" highlight="" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" @|\color{green!70!black}\bfseries type="text"|@>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input id= "signin-password" highlight="" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" type="password">
    </div>
    <button highlight="" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
    </form>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the package offers you many features for highlighting keywords, comments, etc. Please refer to the package documentation.

Comment: It worked exactly in a way I hoped. It also works for manually defined colors, too. Thanks a lot.