# Use color in verbatim environment

Tags: color, verbatim

Inside the verbatim environment, is it possible to use a different color, please? For example, I want `a` to be normal, i.e., black. But I want `b` to be red.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
a (black)
b (I want this letter to be red)
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Follow-up Question:

The solution provided by Ignasi was neat. However, there is a problem. If I need to write the entire verbatim in a non-black color, then it will not work.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

I want the following to look exactly like the way I put, i.e., like an align. But it displays in one line. How to fix?

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\textcolor{red}{
a = b + 1
  = x + y
  = s + t
  = c - d
  = o * p
}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `fancyvrb` will do this See this : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91259/changing-color-of-text-snippet-in-a-verbatim-environment

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Not exactly the same solution pointed by flav:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
a (black)
\textcolor{red}{b} (I want this letter to be red)
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: Credits to [`fancyvrb` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fancyvrb#page=14)

Answer to `follow-up` question:

To change the color for all contents of `verbatim` use a colored scope.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
a (black)
\textcolor{red}{b} (I want this letter to be red)
\end{Verbatim}

{
\color{blue}%
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
a (black)
\textcolor{red}{b} (I want this letter to be red)
\end{Verbatim}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would assume that this idea can be extended to other common font. For example, if I want to use bold face for certain letter, then I can just use \textbf{b}. Right?

Comment: @LaTeXFan Yes. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. It worked. Cheers.

Comment: I have a follow-up question for you. Thanks.

Comment: @LaTeXFan `{\color{red}\begin{Verbatim}...\end{Verbatim}}`

Comment: It's not possible without the `Verbatim` environment, then? The 'entire-block-gets-coloured' thing?

Answer (score 12):

A `verbatimbox` approach, using `<` and `>` as active delimiters of the red text.  Invoked by providing the `\vbdelim` macro as the optional argument to the `verbnobox` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,verbatimbox}
\catcode`>=\active %
\catcode`<=\active %
\def\openesc{\color{red}}
\def\closeesc{\color{black}}
\def\vbdelim{\catcode`<=\active\catcode`>=\active%
\def<{\openesc}
\def>{\closeesc}}
\catcode`>=12 %
\catcode`<=12 %
\begin{document}
\begin{verbnobox}[\vbdelim]
a (black)
<b> (I want this letter to be <red>)
\end{verbnobox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a more general version in which the color can be provided as an optional argument to `<`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,verbatimbox}
\catcode`>=\active %
\catcode`<=\active %
\newcommand\openesc[1][red]{\color{#1}}
\def\closeesc{\color{black}}
\def\vbdelim{\catcode`<=\active\catcode`>=\active%
\def<{\openesc}
\def>{\closeesc}}
\catcode`>=12 %
\catcode`<=12 %
\begin{document}
\begin{verbnobox}[\vbdelim]
a (black)
<b> (I want this letter to be <red>)
<[blue!45]c> and this one to be <[blue!45]blue!45>
\end{verbnobox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is wonderful. But the previous one does look tider.

Answer (score 11):

If your `verbatim` environment doesn't really contain stuff that requires it (that is, it's just regular text), consider using the `alltt` environment (from [`alltt`](//ctan.org/pkg/alltt)):

> The `alltt` pack­age de­fines the `alltt` en­vi­ron­ment which is like the `ver­ba­tim` en­vi­ron­ment ex­cept that `\` and braces have their usual mean­ings. Thus, other com­mands and en­vi­ron­ments can ap­pear within an `alltt` en­vi­ron­ment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alltt,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
a (black)
\textcolor{red}{b} (I want this letter to be red)
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want **all verbatim text** in your document to be of your selected colour, you can just redefine the commands in the preamble using the package `newverbs`

```
\usepackage{newverbs}
% etc
\renewenvironment{verbatim}
{\semiverbatim\color{red}}
{\endsemiverbatim}
\renewcommand{\verb}{\collectverb{\color{red}}}
```

(example with colour red)