# Command chars inside colored Verbatim

Tags: verbatim

I want to use color inside verbatim, so the answer here is exactly what I want to use: [Use color in verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370334/use-color-in-verbatim-environment), however I would like to use more complex `commandchars` (from the answer to the question I just linked), so instead of having 1 character for each `commandchar`, I could use perhaps 3 consecutive characters to express 1 `commandchar`. This because the contents inside the verbatim will be programming code and I would like to make sure that it does not contain any character that LateX might interpret as a `commandchar`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you use verbatim then? Packages like `listings` are written for that purpose...

Comment: because I'm using Flex to generate a Scanner that reads C code and I want it to write the output to latex with the different tokens differentiated by color.

Comment: Well, I do not know Flex, but I know that the listings package is intended to display code listings with colored keywords, strings, comment etc. according to the given language and customization. But let's wait for someone else who knows Verbatim better...

Comment: The thing is that yes, I do want to do what Listing does, Syntax Highlighting, but I want the Highlighting to be "homebrewed", from my own Syntactical Analyser (analyses keywords just like listings does, but I created it with my own rules), for now I believe \verb command will work as I can define colors for it outside of its 'verbatim' environment and only relies on 1 commandchar. Thank you.

Comment: Just as a hint: If you've got some knowledge about syntactical analysis and want manual configuration *and you know pygmentize* `minted` could be an option as it relies on the very flexible pygmentize lexers and styles (you could write on your own, if there's none for your language of choice).

Comment: You only need your latex code generator to escape the original `\ ` to `\textbackslash{}` and  `{`,  `}` to `\{`,  resp. `\}` and then insert your commands for colors. Assuming `[commandchars=\\\{\}]` optional argument to Verbatim of package `fncyvrb`.