# How to add color to text snippets in modified verbatim environment

Tags: color, verbatim, fancyvrb

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{framed,color,verbatim}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.9, .9, .9}

\newenvironment{code}%
   {\snugshade\verbatim}%
   {\endverbatim\endsnugshade}
```

I have a new environment for background grey shade in latex verbatim environment. But, I also want to add color to some specific text snippets inside the environment. What I have-

```
\begin{code}
black text snippet default ; red text snippet
\end{code}
```

I tried to change it to the following but with no change in output except the new command itself gets added as a code instead of being implemented.

```
\begin{code}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
black text snippet default ; \color{red}{red text snippet}
\end{code}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: There are several answers here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370334/use-color-in-verbatim-environment, that seem to address your need.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I tried the solution there and it is not working. That is the issue I mentioned above.

Comment: The answer you are *trying* to mimic uses the `fancyvrb` package, which you are not showing in your code.  From that package, it uses the `Verbatim` environment, which your code also does not show.  In your code snippet, you are using an optional argument in your user-defined `code` environment, which is not set up to take optional arguments.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes How do I set it up to take optional arguments? I have used fancyvrb and I thought defining a new environment over verbatim would still ensure that.

Comment: Because it changes token catcodes, verbatim code is a delicate thing, which almost always defies being placed inside a user-defined environment, such as your `code` environment.  The solution is to use the *explicit* code as presented in the referenced answer; namely, use the `Verbatim` environment provided by `fancyvrb`, rather than trying to embed it inside of your own `code` environment.  The `Verbatim` environment is already set up to take optional arguments and to make use of `commandchars` escape characters.